# Multiple jpath to Query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, jpath

I predefined my data source. I want to specify multiple paths in one query. For example Here is my datasource ;

```
  const Jforce_DataSource = {
    Name: 'Jforce',
    ConnectionProperties: {
      DataProvider: 'JSON',
      ConnectString: 'endpoint=http://localhost:3001/',
    },
  };

  const dataSources = [
    {
      id: 'Jforce',
      title: 'Jforce',
      template: Jforce_DataSource,
      canEdit: false,
      datasets: collections.map((collection) => {
        return {
          id: collection,
          title: collection,
          template: {
            Name: collection,
            Query: { DataSourceName: 'Jforce', CommandText: `uri=/${collection};jpath=$.[*].Statistics.Platforms[*];jpath=$.[*].Measurements[*]` },
            
            Fields: [
              { Name: '_id', DataField: '_id' },
              { Name: 'Date', DataField: 'Run.Date' },
              { Name: 'Index', DataField: 'Run.Index' },
              { Name: 'ScenarioName', DataField: 'Run.Scenario.Name' },
              { Name: 'ScenarioDatabase', DataField: 'Run.Scenario.Database' },
              { Name: 'SvnAddress', DataField: 'Run.Svn.Address' },
              { Name: 'SvnRevision', DataField: 'Run.Svn.Revision' },

              { Name: 'PlatformProfile', DataField: 'PProfile' },
              { Name: 'PlatformType', DataField: 'PType' },
              { Name: 'PlatformForce', DataField: 'PForce' },
              { Name: 'PlatformTotal', DataField: 'PTotal' },
              { Name: 'PlatformWrecked', DataField: 'PWrecked' },
              { Name: 'PlatformDestroyed', DataField: 'PDestroyed' },
              { Name: 'WeaponProfile', DataField: 'WProfile' },
              { Name: 'WeaponType', DataField: 'WType' },
              { Name: 'WeaponForce', DataField: 'WForce' },
              { Name: 'WeaponTotal', DataField: 'WTotal' },
              { Name: 'WeaponHit', DataField: 'WHit' },
              { Name: 'WeaponMissed', DataField: 'WMissed' },

              { Name: 'VariableType', DataField: 'VType' },
              { Name: 'VariableConfiguration', DataField: 'VConfiguration' },
              { Name: 'VariableValue', DataField: 'VVaue' },

              { Name: 'MeasurementType', DataField: 'MType' },
              { Name: 'MeasurementConfiguration', DataField: 'MConfiguration' },
              { Name: 'MeasurementValue', DataField: 'MValue' },
            ],
          },
          canEdit: true,
        };
      }),
    },
  ];
```

I want to retrieve both Statistics.Platforms and Measurements. When I try

```
CommandText: `uri=/${collection};jpath=$.[*].Statistics.Platforms[*];jpath=$.[*].Measurements[*]`
```

I can retrieve Measurements but I can not Statistics.Platforms. I'm glad if you can help.